# How to get events in the last 24 hours with SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I have a column with datetime entries, and I would like to get all the items from the last 24 hours.  Right now I'm trying:

```
SELECT * FROM " + SQLHelp.LOG_TABLE + " WHERE " + SQLHelp.TIME_COLUMN + "> datetime('now','-1day')
```

where `SQLHelp.LOG_TABLE and SQLHelp.TIME_COLUMN` are the names of the table and column respectively.

Comment: What *data* is stored in TIME_COLUMN? What "doesn't work" with that is posted? Also, I have only used `'-1 day'` (note the space), so make sure the format is correct to `datetime`.

Comment: TIME_COLUMN has a datetime, which I know is formatted correctly.  Nothing is selected, even though events have been added within the last 24 hours. Good catch on the missed space.  It turns out that was my problem.  I feel incredibly stupid.

Comment: Glad it was solved - "self answer" (and accept) this question so it can be of use to others.

Answer (score 3):

There must be a space between `-1` and `day`; `datetime('now','-1 day')` works as expected.